# Inserting comments into typename will give error

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor

Following line is written in the C program

```
in/*hello*/t k; error or not
```

According to me,first preprocessor would remove the comments from the code and then code will go to compiler so the code that would go to compiler is

```
int k;
```

which is perfectly ok.

but actually when I am running this on gcc compiler it's giving compiler error as

> `in`,`k`,`t` is not defined

Comment: it won't read the comments as code, but it will not simply treat it as if it wasn't there at all. You are breaking up a keyword which is not good. If you do int /*hello*/ k; //not an error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510869/716443

Comment: Please give questions a decent title that let's us distinguish them from others.

Answer (score 9):

The comment in the code will be replaced to a white space by the compiler. So

```
in/*hello*/t k;
```

will become

```
in t k;
```

which is not correct.

> #### C11 §5.1.1.2 Translation phases
>
> 3 The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. **Each comment is replaced by one space character.** New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.

Comment: you can test pre-processor output by running gcc -E file.c

Answer (score 3):

From C11 5.1.1.2 Translation phases (my emphasis)

> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and
>   sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source
>   file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial
>   comment. **Each comment is replaced by one space character**

So, as Yu Hao notes, your comment is replaced by a space by the preprocessor.  You can test this yourself by using `gcc -R your_file.c` (gcc) or `cl /EP your_file.c` (msvc) to view the output from the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processor does not remove the comments from the code. What it does is ignore whatever is there in the comment and read the next meaningful character putting a blank space(White Space) for comments. SO you'll get the error as these variables are not defined.