# comments in c macro definition

Tags: c, macros, comments

There is not much information about this. Is this the one and only way to do comment in C macro definition? Or can I make add comment using another way?

```
#define TEST(a, b) \
{ \
    bool aGb = false;\
    bool bGc = false;\
    /* comment is here */ \
    if (a > b) \
    {\
        ... \
    }\
}
```

Comment: What does you compiler documentation say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510869/does-the-c-preprocessor-strip-comments-or-expand-macros-first

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
#define DOC(ignored)
```

And combine like so:

```
#define TEST(a, b) \
{ \
    bool aGb = false; \
    bool bGc = false; \
    DOC((This is a comment, hello world!)) \
    if (a > b) \
    { \
        ... \
    } \
}
```

Naturally you can't use the C99 comment style with `//`, since it would ignore the rest of the line and prevent you from creating a multi-line macro.

I would personally suggest just getting used to `/* comment */` style. For a start, people using syntax-highlighting IDEs with your code won't see the highlighting if you use this `DOC` macro above.

Answer (score 1):

The only limitation which adds to those already present when commenting "real" C sources is, that you may not add **anything** on a macro's "source" line **after** the final backslash.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a macro's "source" line". Can you be more precise?