# Exclude line from compilation via Makro C++

Tags: c++, compilation, macros, precompile

I've got some problem, which might be simple to solve.

I have code like this:

```
#define _MG_ALL //This might be defined in some other headerfile

#ifndef _MG_ALL
#define MG_ALL <?????>
#else
#define MG_ALL <nothing>
#endif
```

In the code it is used like this:

```
ALL foo = thisIsSomeFunc(foo);
```

This line should only be compiled, if `_ALL` is defined. This could also be solved by using this:

```
#ifdef ALL
    foo = thisIsSomeFunc(int foo);
#endif
```

But I would prefer just one short macro in the same line.

Comment: Could you not just uncomment the line? `#define ALL //`

Comment: @muXXmit2X I tried that, but it didnt work.

Comment: I've just read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1510869/4711812) that comment stripping is done before macro expension is performed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is defining the macro like so:

```
#ifdef _ALL
#define ALL if(1)
#else
#define ALL if(0)
#endif
```

When you use it this it will produce code similar to this

```
ALL std::cout << "Debug Message" << std::endl;
 ==> if(1) std::cout << "Debug Message" << std::endl;
```

A good compiler should recognize the constant value in the `if-statement` and should only compile the right part (`1 ==> if part, 0 ==> nothing`).