# Why do I get an "Expected a declaration" error on C++ macro expanding into a comment?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have following macro:

```
#define DEFINE_EXPORT_MODULE(__module__) /##*Exported by __module__*/
```

If I use it like this: `DEFINE_EXPORT_MODULE(foo)` it expands properly into `/*Exported by foo*/` but I still get the E0169 error: "Expected a declaration."

What is wrong?

Edit: Here is how I use it in my code.

```
#define DEFINE_EXPORT_MODULE(__module__) /##*Exported by __module__*/

DEFINE_EXPORT_MODULE("foo.dll") //this produces the error.
void Function(void);
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Don’t use names starting with double underscores for your own names, these are all reserved for compiler use.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  g++ throws an error with this.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  I didn't think it was legal for the preprocessor to form new tokens.  e.g.  to form `/*` should elicit an error like _pasting formed `/*`, an invalid preprocessing token_

Comment: @Cubic Changed it from ```__module__``` to ```_module```.
 Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Why are you using the C preprocessor to embed comments?  Who will ever see them?  What is your target audience for the comment?  Where are you hoping this comment show up?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510919/1563833) may be relevant: regarding the behaviour of comments in the translation phase.

Comment: @Wyck I use them for myself to remember which module exports which function I import.

I don't want to write ```/*Exported by ...*/``` like 30 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the paste operator must be a valid token after macros are expanded.

Trying to create a comment fails because comments are removed before pre-processing starts.

See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

Comment: You should quote the passage that goes: > A ## operator between any two successive identifiers in the replacement-list runs parameter replacement on the two identifiers (which are not macro-expanded first) and then concatenates the result. This operation is called "concatenation" or "token pasting". Only tokens that form a valid token together may be pasted: identifiers that form a longer identifier, digits that form a number, or operators + and = that form a +=. A comment cannot be created by pasting / and * because comments are removed from text before macro substitution is considered ...