# doxygen compact #define Documentation

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I often have code like this:

```
#define limit_0 1.0f    /**< Limit 0 */
#define limit_1 3.5     /**< Limit 1 */
#define limit_2 2       /**< Limit 2 */
```

and in this case the Doxygen HTML documentation ("Macro Definition Documentation") looks bad. A lot of overhead and a lot of lines.

I like the compact Enumerations documentation. For the example above I would like to have something like:

| name | value | details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| limit_0 | 1.0f | Limit 0 |
| limit_1 | 3.5 | Limit 1 |
| limit_2 | 2 | Limit 2 |

Is this possible?

Comment: In general documenting a `define` after a name is not the best idea as it get into the code used by doxygen as well and give some unexpected results e.g. if case `if (x < limit_1)`. Maybe a bit a better layout for you would be to use the `\brief` command. Further there are, to the best of my knowledge, no solutions for this.

Comment: The Doxygen manual says that `<`-marked documentation comments can only be used to document *members* and *parameters*, so you should not use them to document macros.

Comment: Adding \brief makes the output much better. Now everything is documented in the Macros section and there is no “Detailed Macro Description” anymore. Thx albert

The inline documentation is working and should be safe, since the comments are replaced with a single space in the tokenization phase, which happens before the preprocessing phase where macros are expanded. At least since C99.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510869/does-the-c-preprocessor-strip-comments-or-expand-macros-first